# How can i make this linq query cleaner and more reusable?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, coding-style

I have a linq query that returns the count of several ring sizes. However even though it is reusablable to an extent i want to see if i can improve it.

```
    private async Task<RingSizeLettersDto> CountOfLettersByRingFingerAsync(Func<RingSize, string> selector)
    {
        var ringSizes = await _ringSizeRepository.Get();

        RingSizeLettersDto ringSizeLetters = new RingSizeLettersDto();

        ringSizeLetters.G = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "G").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.H = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "H").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.I = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "I").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.J = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "J").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.K = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "K").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.L = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "L").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.M = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "M").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.N = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "N").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.O = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "O").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.P = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "P").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.Q = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "Q").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.R = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "R").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.S = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "S").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.T = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "T").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.U = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "U").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.V = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "V").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.W = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "W").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.X = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "X").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.Y = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "Y").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.Z = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "Z").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.Z1 = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "Z1").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.Z2 = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "Z2").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.Z3 = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "Z3").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.Z4 = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "Z4").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.Z5 = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "Z5").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.Z6 = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "Z6").Count();
        ringSizeLetters.NA = ringSizes.Where(x => selector(x) == "N/A").Count();

        return ringSizeLetters;

    }
```

Comment: Perhaps this is a situation where you would be better off looping over ```ringsizes``` once and conditionally incrementing counters manually? That is, if performance is an issue

Comment: Without knowing your specific use case it seems like this could be modelled a bit more cleanly. It could be a Dictionary<string, int>, where string is the letter and int is the count. Or you could have the a more generic model, where instead of having separate properties for each letter, you'd just have a string called "Letter" (and int count). In both those cases you could get away with one query.

Comment: `ringSizeLetters.Z6 = ringSizes.Count(x => selector(x) == "Z6")` would work too

Answer (score 1):

I have two improvements in mind:

- You can use `Count(x => selector(x) == "G")`, which will reduce 1 method invocation per line.
- You can create a `Dictionary<string, int>` (probably `char` as key can be more accurate) which represents the count by character, then elsewhere in you application you can access it using the character you want to search for as a key:

```
var ringSizes = new[] { 1, 2, 2 };
var ringSizeLetters = ringSizes.GroupBy(x => Selector(x))
     .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, v => v.Count());

var ocurrences = ringSizeLetters["A"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether your specific use case allows for this, a cleaner solution would be to use a Dictionary. Judging from your code the best type would be `IDictionary<string, int>`. In this, the string key is the identifier (such as 'Z1') and the integer value is the result of `.Count()`.

I've coughed up a possible code sample below;

```cs
public static IDictionary<string, int> GetRingSizeLettersAsDict(
    IEnumerable<string> sizeLetters,
    IEnumerable<object> ringSizes)
{
    IDictionary<string, int> ringSizeLetters = new();

    sizeLetters.Select(
        sl => ringSizeLetters.Add(
            sl,
            ringSizes.Where(rs => selector(rs).Equals(sl)).Count())
    );

    return ringSizeLetters;
}
```

This is just one of many solutions, but it should do the same as your code example, provided it fits your use case.

Answer (score 0):

This is type of speudo-code but something like this should do the trick..

It is done via System.Reflection

```
                PropertyInfo[] properties = ringSizeLetters.GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                {
                   var propertyName = property.Name;
                   var ringsizeValue = ringSizes.SingleOrDefault(x=> x.PROPERTYNAME == propertyName)
    
                   // if it finds ringsize Value 
                  if(ringsizeValue != null)
                  {
                     property.SetValue(ringSizeLetters, ringsizeValue.Count());
                  }
    
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can keep all your properties if you really want them:

```
class RingSizeDto{

  public int G { get; set;}
  public int H { get; set;}
```

... and avoid reflection by backing them with e.g. a dictionary instead:

```
class RingSizeDto{

  private Dictionary<string, int> _ringSizes = new();

  public int G { get => _ringSizes[nameof(G)]; set _ringSizes[nameof(G)] = value; }
  public int H { get => _ringSizes[nameof(H)]; set _ringSizes[nameof(H)] = value; }
  ...
```

This means the sizes can be set all in one go by providing the dictionary:

```
  public RingSizeDto(Dictionary <string, int> sizes){
    _ringSizes = sizes;
  }
```

And the dictionary can be generated by query e.g.

```
var sizes = someSizeList.GroupBy(s => s.SizeLetter).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

new RingSizeDto(sizes);
```

Note; if your list doesn't have every possible size, you'll want to avoid a crash on the dictionary access by using TryGetValue instead

```
public int G { get => _ringSizes.TryGetValue(nameof(G), out var x) ? x : 0; set _ringSizes[nameof(G)] = value; }
```